# Textmate check spelling everywhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, spell-checking

Is there any way to check spelling for ALL the words that I type in Textmate?

It's hard to believe but I actually use legit English words for ALL my variables and class names - thus unhighlighted typos are just killing me.

It would be nice if there was a way to check spelling for words with special characters (@uesr, crreunt_uesr)

I am using Textmate for Rails if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text);

> 4.10 Spell Checking
>
> TextMate supports the system wide 'Check Spelling as You Type'. This
>   can be changed in the Edit → Spelling submenu.
>
> You can bring up the context sensitive menu for a misspelled word to
>   get spelling suggestions.
>
> Since TextMate is intended for structured text it is possible to
>   exclude parts of the document from being checked. **This is done by
>   creating a preferences item in the bundle editor, setting
>   spellChecking to 0 and filling in the scope selector with the selector
>   to target for no spell checking.**
>
> By default spell checking is disabled for source code except strings
>   and comments and also for keywords, tags and similar in HTML, LaTeX,
>   Markdown, etc.