# spellchecking code comments in Textmate

Tags: javascript, textmate, textmatebundles, sublimetext

Does anyone know of a plugin I can use to spell check the comments in my code?

I'm always doing things like this

```
//Retrns porduct name in upercase   
function getUpperCaseProductName(){
    var productName =  Myobj.currentProduct.data.name;
    return productName.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: This question indicates that spell checking in comments happens by default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988777/textmate-check-spelling-everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a textmate plugin, but I'm pretty sure it does this already via Edit → Spelling, which is enabled by default for comments. Start by checking that you don't have this turned off for comments, or set to the wrong language.

It's unlikely that someone will develop a custom plugin to do something that textmate already has as a feature.

BTW, the //Retrns example you give above is joined to the two slashes. No word in the dictionary has two slashes at the start, so it may be missing it for this reason. If this is the problem, file a bug report with the textmate guys, or perhaps consider moving to a more feature-rich editor if it bothers you a lot ([PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) picks up that typo just fine, and you can also check the names of variables and functions if you want to be really pernickety).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Spelling option under Edit in Textmate2.

I think it does not differentiate between code and comment for Spell Check.